# using css grid with material UI components to get responsive design

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm trying to use css grid to get a responsive design using the below code and used the min-content and max-content to determine the width of the grid items. But it isn't working. Any ideas on how to fix this? Here is the demo code https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-chatterjee-6yk6l

On a sidenote, I'm aware that there is a `<Grid>` component but I'd like to try with the CSS grid.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        gridGap: 10,
        margin: 10,
        alignItems: "center",
        gridTemplateColumns:
          "repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min-content, max-content)"
      }}
    >
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>{" "}
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>{" "}
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>{" "}
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Which part is not working, the code in codesandbox seems to be running fine.

Comment: The buttons should arrange in multiple columns and rows depending on the size of the screen.